# Is faces context available in HttpSessionListener?

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-listeners

I am trying to run below code in my application from HttpSessionListener.But i see different outputs for session id.Session Init Listener is triggered by default when i start my jsf application.

```
@Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        FacesContext fc=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        System.out.println("session id01-->"+se.getSession().getId());
        HttpSession session= ((HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getSession(false);
        System.out.println("httpSessionId-->" + (session!=null?session.getId():""));
}
```

First sysout prints session id.
Second one is printing null.

Why faces context is returning session as null even though session is created ?

Regards,
-Vissu Adusumalli.

Comment: The `HttpSessionListener` gets called when a new HTTP session is created. The faces context however, gets the session from [the current request](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/bbac72aabda02f7e605d05f71da0be2fd0814ce7/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/context/ExternalContextImpl.java). If session has just been created, it might still not be linked to the current request.

Answer (score 0):

Since `fc.getExternalContext()` does not throw an NPE, the FacesContext **is** available. Why the session from the `ServletContext` (that ishat the external context is, not a JSF thing) is null is a different question. It might simply not have been set yet

Comment: It does not throw NPE but i do not see session from faces context even though session is created and i am inside sessioncreated() method

Comment: So?  Being in the sessioncreated method does (as it seems) not mean it is already set in the servletcontext. My answer answers your question from your title